ElasticSearch multi-field query aborted
ElasticSearch: If a search word needs to match multiple fields, only one field needs to be queried. However, if a specific field matches, no other results are returned. How should this query statement be written?
Currently, the system queries data based on the sequence of different fields. If a specified field is queried and a result is returned, the system does not query the remaining fields. Is there a way to write this logic as a query?
The way I'm doing it now is to run the following statements in order. If the first code is returned, I don't continue the query.
GET metadata/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"simple_query_string": {
          "query": "test",
          "fields": ["code.keyword"]
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}

GET metadata/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {"simple_query_string": {
          "query": "test",
          "fields": ["instanceName.keyword"]
        }}
      ],
      "must_not": [
         {"simple_query_string": {
          "query": "test",
          "fields": ["code.keyword"]
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}

GET metadata_hw_dam-ai_dataset/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "*test*",
            "fields": [
              "instanceName.keyword"
            ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "test",
            "fields": [
              "code.keyword"
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "simple_query_string": {
            "query": "test",
            "fields": [
              "instanceName.keyword"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


No. If your logic is: if you have a match with a field, don't search in others, the solution is to create separate queries for each field.
In my opinion, this doesn't make sense.
The correct thing is to have a query capable of matching multiple fields at once.
What is the point of avoiding matching in more than one field?

I have three documents.
{"id": "test"}
{"name": "test"}
{"name": "demo"}
If test is matched using multiple fields, only {"id": "test"} is found in the result, even though {"name": "test"} is also matched. But if you match it with demo, the result is {"name": "demo"}. Because of the restriction on the id field, if the id field of a document is matched, the name field of other documents will not be matched. Is there any logic to find out at once?
